# No application icon in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons

I want to show application icon in Action Bar. Seemingly it's visible by default but not for me. I don't have that icon in any program I made using Android Studio.

I'm not sure which files are responsible for displaying icon in Action Bar. I guess it will be helpful:

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lislav.conrpeselwieotobie"
>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayInfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.lislav.conrpeselwieotobie.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `appcompat-v7` support library for support with Android 5.0, there would not be an action bar logo because of the new design concept.

Comment: I don't know if I'm using it (it's just my third day in Android programming :( ), but it seems that's this. So I have to deal with it or it's any way that I can display this icon?

Comment: Hmm. I remember when I first started Android programming :). If you want to check if you are using it, go to `build.gradle`, and see if you have `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` under `dependencies {`.

Comment: Yes, I have this line. Yh, so much time spent on trying to display this icon.. Thanks for your answer! :)